# How to tell if a user is on Device Home Screen

Tags: android

I have a app that displays a chat head bubble bubble similar to the Facebook messenger app. I want to be able to have it only appear when the user is in the home screen and not follow you when you go to other apps. Is there anyway to know when the user is in the device home screen? Couldn't find much information on this can anyone point me to the right direction if this is even possible? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it be getting the running tasks and filter them by using `Intent.CATEGORY_HOME` and `Intent.ACTION_MAIN` like that:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName currentTask = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
mPackageManager = getPackageManager();

List<ResolveInfo> appList = mPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
for(int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) {
ResolveInfo apl = appList.get(i);
if(currentTask.getPackageName().equals(apl.activityInfo.packageName)) {
    Log.e(TAG, "ONHOMESCREEN");
   }
}
```

and also add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```